# How does Android's WifiManager new 'EXTRA_RESULTS_UPDATED' work?

Tags: android, wifimanager

I noticed a new boolean extra [EXTRA_RESULTS_UPDATED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#EXTRA_RESULTS_UPDATED) in the WifiManager class.

The documentation, however, is somewhat minimal:

> Lookup key for a boolean representing the result of previous startScan() operation, reported with SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION.

So how does this work, exactly? Is is only true when my app requested a startScan() and the scan is completed? Is it true whenever some app, including mine, called it? Or is it always true whenever a scan has completed regardless of startScan() was called by an app, system, etc?

Answer (score 0):

Tells you whether the previous startScan() succeeded or not. The javadoc for SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION is clearer about this: "EXTRA_RESULTS_UPDATED indicates if the scan was completed successfully."

For example, in O background apps can't successfully start a scan more than once every 30 minutes or something like that. See https://developer.android.com/preview/features/background-location-limits.html for details.